# Parallax and fixed nav

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I using a parallax effect on a home page with a fixed nav bar that works fine, however for the other pages that don't have the parallax effect, the fixed nav is broken.

you can see the working parallax/fixed nav [here](http://wearerain.co/test/s-index.html)

and the broken fixed nav [here](http://wearerain.co/test/ri-expert.html)

Comment: Just to clarify, I'm trying to implement a sticky fixed nav bar with parallax scrolling on the homepage, and the rest of the site without parallax, just the sticky fixed nav.

My limited coding skills don't permit me to figure out what the conflict is - the overall effect of parallax and sticky nav works on the homepage (although the nav bar still doesnt show up when you scroll), but on the pages that dont use the parallax effect, the sticky nav disappears altogether when I scroll down the page.

Comment: It looks like it's `transform: translateZ(0px)` on the body that causes it not to stay fixed on the non-parallax page. Edit: you're likely getting down-voted, not because you didn't explain the issue, but because you posted links instead of showing a minimal, complete and verifiable example of your code.

Comment: thanks for the answer mark.

I wonder if it may just be easier to separate the css into two files - one for the homepage, and one for the rest of the site...

Comment: Or, if the `transform: translateZ(0px)` is only required by the home page, you could just embed that CSS rule on the  homepage and delete it from the linked CSS file.

Comment: that worked! well at least for desktops - not sure what it looks like on android or ios, but I'll check that later.  Thanks Mark!

Comment: Np! Chrome's emulation option in Dev Tools has a few Android presets you could try. Not perfect, but it has served me well over the years.

Comment: Would be best to add some identifier/class to your body tag, such as `home-page`, `category-page`, `checkout-page`, etc, so later on you can easily apply various styles using same css. Also, those classes can help you choose which scripts you wanna run, too.

Comment: thanks for the advice skobaljic - unfortunately i'm not really a coder so don't know what you mean! :p

Comment: @skobaljic is saying something like `<body class='home-page'>` for the home page and `<body class='checkout-page'>` for the checkout page, etc. This would allow you to define `body.home-page { transform: translateZ(0px) }` so you can use that in your included CSS file - which prevents you from having to separate one CSS rule from the rest of the rules (so you know where to look for ALL CSS rules immediately); it also allows for easier use of the rule in the future. Ex. If the checkout page uses parallax too it could be `body.home-page, body.checkout-page { transform: translateZ(0px) }`.

Comment: perfect - thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

@tony you need to remove margin from **full-wrapper** element

for example:
[image]